# simulator for semantic project

Tags: semantics, simulator

i want simulate a semantic security project that detecting and classifying web application attacks.
The ontological model was developed using Description Logic that was based on the Web Ontology Language (OWL)and are implemented using the Apache JENA framework.
which simulator software is appropriation for simulate this system ?